# Why JSON.stringify giving JSON undefined error?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am trying to use `JSON.stringify` in my javascript page (EXTJS) code but it's giving me JSON is undefined error. Error happends only in IE (ver.10). This code will work in FF and Chrome. Below is a sample code that I am trying to use. Why is it failing? This seems like a valid example and works in other browsers. Thanks in advance.

```
var contact = new Object(); 
contact.firstname = "Joe";
contact.surname = "Smith";
contact.gendere= "male";
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(contact);
```

Comment: What happens when you use {} instead of new Object()? Does it work if you use a hardcoded object like { firstname : 'Joe', surname : 'Smith', gendere : 'male' }?

Comment: Hi schlingel, I get same error "JSON undefined" when I hard code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you only need to support IE10.  If you need to use earlier versions of IE (some people still need to support IE6) you can use the JS implementation of JSON: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: Ok I tried <!DOCTYPE html> but no effect, same problem, JSON undetified error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JS11 did you try using the JSON-js implementation from my response?

Comment: Hi Nirk,  I am currently using json2.js and i notice this on the link you recomended: "json.js: This file does everything that json2.js does. It also adds a
toJSONString method and a parseJSON method to Object.prototype. Use of this
file is not recommended."

Comment: Use of this file is not recommended - portion is what confuses me

Comment: @JS11 use the file json2.js -- that replicates the JSON object (with parse and stringify).  json.js was an older interface

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I fixed the path to json2.js file and now it is working.

Comment: Why don't you use the Ext.JSON.encode method? You already have it included in your page, why load another library?

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of your document (and of course remove any other doctype you might have).

Without it, IE10 is in a weird compatibility mode where many "new" features aren't available, for example `JSON`.

Comment: This is truth,and if you are doing new development, the only solution. HOWEVER, if you are maintaining and old page that relies on the broken layout, you can include json.js from the json.org website.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher That's true. But do people still maintain applications compatible with IE8 and not compatible with other browsers ?

Comment: Not so much on public facing websites, but there are still a lot of intraweb and private websites that have not been brought up to date.  A lot are limited to older IE engines to do ActiveX dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You have the framework already, use it:
Ext.JSON.encode/decode  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.JSON